# How can i change the mono runtime which is used for building in visual studio for mac?

Tags: mono, visual-studio-mac

I'm currently using Visual Studio for Mac and i changed the active runtime under Settings / project / .net-runtimes to 5.2.0.104 - however it keeps telling me that it's running with 5.0.1.1

Is there a trick to make it change the used version apart from physically removing other runtimes? I've both restarted VS + Mac but neither one did changed the runtime version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Visual Studio is currently running on Mono 5.2.0.104" message tells you what the Visual Studio for Mac is running on. It does not indicate what your project will be run with.

You can still build and run your project on a different runtime and that will be the one selected and marked as Default in the .NET runtimes list, which is shown above the message about which Mono version that Visual Studio for Mac is running on.

Comment: I'll try to verify which mono version was used to built my assemblies somehow and then mark his as answer. thanks for your reply